# Streams, ReadOnlyStreams and memory traffic

Tags: .net, memory, stream, immutability

I'm investigating the memory traffic issues in our application and find out that a lot of wasted memory is caused by the Stream API.

So, probably you are familiar with the method.

```
public abstract int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);
```

The new interface supported the Span as a first argument.
It looks logical as the output buffer is supposed to be mutable.

The problem appears when you try to implement smth like [ReadOnlyStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/jj667151(v=exchg.140)), which has almost the same API. And here we have stuff I do not understand.

The implementation of the Read method for ReadOnlyStream

```
public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            ...//some checks
            
            int chkOffset = (int)_Offset;
            count = Math.Min(count, _Bytes.Length - chkOffset);
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(_Bytes, chkOffset, buffer, offset, count);
            chkOffset += count;
            _Offset = chkOffset;
            return count;
        }
```

So, we copy a buffer to the preliminarily allocated array. It seems like this is the only way to protect stream data from coping, but we overload the GC.

Ok... I assume we are trying to fit the Stream interface, but then it looks strange because there is no chance to make it read-only in some appropriate way.

Do you have any assumptions why there are no any ReadOnly constructions (SpanReadOnly for instance) in the Stream interface in .NET? Maybe there are some limitations I am not familiar with.

Maybe be you have some proposals for implementing the allocation-free access to the Stream data. (except reading a single byte)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Streams implementation cannot/do not/shouldn't guaranty that some internal buffer is kept after reading! SpanReadOnly should refer to some immutable buffer to be safe. So, there is no other choice than copy the read data to a new buffer.